# C# Building a Method Variable inside another Method Variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, methods

I have a method and I am trying to add another method as a list variable so that I can add multiple Error's per file. I am currently passing the files list variable to multiple different functions. I would like the Error variable to be contained in the files, but I have been unable to figure it out. Thanks!

```
    class AllFiles
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string FileType { get; set; }
        ...
        public List<ErrorClass> Error { get; set; }
    }

    class ErrorClass
    {
        public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
        public int Total { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

I use the following to initialize my files as a list so I can add multiple files.

```
        List<AllFiles> files = new List<AllFiles>();
        files.Add(new AllFiles());
```

I am wanting it to look like the following:

```
files[0]
   Error[0]
   Error[1]
files[1]
   Error[0]
   Error[1]
   Error[2]
files[2]
   Error[0]
   ...
```

Comment: What problem are you having (aside from using "uncommon" terminology)?

Comment: The `AllFiles` class should be named `File` or something like that.  It's not plural, and it's not "All".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the `List<ErrorClass>` (ideally) inside the `AllFiles` class' constructor, and assign it to the `Error` property.

Some other recommendations:

- `AllFiles` is not a good name for a class that represents *one* file
- `ErrorClass` could maybe just be called `Error` or `FileError`
- The `Error` property inside `AllFiles` should be named `Errors` and should have a private setter.

E.g.:

```
class MyFile {
  public MyFile() {
    Errors = new List<MyFileError>();
  }

  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Type { get; set; }
  ...
  public List<MyFileError> Errors { get; private set; }
}

class MyFileError {
  public int Code { get; set; }
  public int Total { get; set; }
  public string Message { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

Depending on your design, you could better encapsulate the error list inside `MyFile` and just expose an `IEnumerable<MyFileError>` and an `AddError(MyFileError)` method.

Comment: You're hiding the property with a local variable. I added some code. Hope it clarifies things...

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize it was that easy. Eventually AllFiles will contain multiple files.